# Styled components – accessing props from a parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a component `Box` that looks like this:

```
const Box = ({ className, country }) => {
  const status = myStatusFunction(country);
  return (
    <div className={className} status={status}>
      {country}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I want to use this component in my view, but also add custom styling to it based on the `status` prop, so my `styled.js` looks like this:

```
import _Box from 'components/Box';

const Box = styled(_Box)`
  ${({ status }) => {
    if (status === 'available') {
      return css`
        background-color: green;
      `;
    }
    return css`
      background-color: red;
    `;
  }}
`
```

The issue here is that the `status` is `undefined` here, so my question is – can you somehow access the `status` prop?

Answer (score 1):

Since React has a top-down data flow this is not possible.
I would suggest to make the `status` variable a prop of the `Box` component to follow the top-down data flow.

The meaning of top-down flow is that information only flows from parent to child. By encapsulating the `_Box` component in the `styled` function, you basically make the `_Box` a child component of the newly created  styled `Box` . This means that you in this situation you are trying to gather information of the child in the parent component.

I hope this answers your question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Wrapper } from './styles.js';

const Box = ({ className, country }) => {
  const status = myStatusFunction(country);

  return (
    <Wrapper className={className} status={status}>
      {country}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

styles.js:

```
export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  ${({ status }) => {
    if (status === 'available') {
      return css`
        background-color: green;
      `;
    }
    return css`
      background-color: red;
    `;
  }}
`
```